# How to cache pages in webview without opening them?

Tags: android, webview

So that's about it, I want webview to download and cache multiple pages when the app is opened so that they're saved for offline use. They're only going to be a few kilobytes each and there's only going to be about 10 of them, we're talking less than 100kb all together, but I want to make sure all the info is up to date when the app is open. How would I do go about doing this? Just somewhere to start would be nice.

Edit: assume internet connection at first, but then this stops and there's no internet after the caching is complete.

Comment: Maybe make the WebView not visible?

Comment: And just open webpage after webpage in an invisible window? That's a good idea. Would that work?

Comment: I never tried, but you could try.

Comment: oh my goodness, that worked. Add it as an answer if you like and I'll accept you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a WebView and make it not visible and load the resources here.

Comment: any other ways?? like without using not visible `WebView`.